# Routing table and multiply hops

Tags: linux, networking, routing, table, gateway

I have 6 networks, I need to connect network 1 and network 5 via five routers. What’s the command to set multiply hops? `ip route add IP_address/mask via IP_adrress dev eth0`, but how do I set next hop? `ip route add IP_address/mask via IP_adrress via IP_address dev eth0`?

Answer (score 1):

In one machine you can only define your next gateway/hop. The second hop is configured as the gateway of the gateway, the third as the gateway of the gateway of the gateway and so on. The hops following to them must be set at those machines following.

So you have to configure all 5 routers with the corresponding next hop.